# Actix System, multiple arbiters = how many threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-actix

**Question** - if you have a single system but have multiple arbiters in it running, is it STILL a single threaded event loop?

Reading through the Actix book - https://actix.rs/book/actix/sec-6-sync-arbiter.html

> When you normally run Actors, there are multiple Actors running on the System's Arbiter thread, using its event loop

And also from https://actix.rs/book/actix/sec-5-arbiter.html

> **While it only uses one thread**, it uses the very efficient event loop pattern which works well for asynchronous events. To handle synchronous, CPU-bound tasks, it's better to avoid blocking the event loop and instead offload the computation to other threads. For this usecase, read the next section and consider using SyncArbiter.

**Question Repeated** - if you have a single system but have multiple arbiters in it running, is it STILL a single threaded event loop?

Example

```
let sys = System::new();
sys.block_on( async move {
    let arbiter1 = Arbiter::new(); // one arbiter here
    arbiter1.spawn( SOME ACTOR);
    let arbiter2 = Arbiter::new(); // another arbiter here
    arbiter2.spanw( SOME OTHER ACTOR);
});

sys.run().unwrap();
```

Does this run in a single thread?

When I log it using log4rs I see the following

```
[actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0]
[actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1]
```

Given that it is system:0 - does this mean it is the same thread just using different arbiters?

Do I need to run multiple `System::new` in order to achieve proper multi threading in actix?

Comment: I have the same dilemma. Did you manage to find out if it's multi-threaded?

Answer (score 3):

Citing the exact same [book](https://actix.rs/book/actix/sec-5-arbiter.html):

> To use Actix in a concurrent way, you can spin up multiple Arbiters using Arbiter::new, ArbiterBuilder, or Arbiter::start.

Also in the docs for `Arbiter::new()`

> Spawn a new Arbiter thread and start its event loop.

So you can definitely have a multi-threaded event loop.

Below is an example. During execution use a process monitoring software to see the number of threads (e.g. Activity Monitor for MacOS, Process Explorer for Windows, htop for Linux).

```
extern crate actix;
use actix::prelude::*;

struct Fibonacci(pub u32);


struct SomeActor;

impl Actor for SomeActor {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}

impl Message for Fibonacci{
    type Result = Result<u64, ()>;
}

impl Handler<Fibonacci> for SomeActor {
    type Result = Result<u64, ()>;

    fn handle(&mut self, msg: Fibonacci, context: &mut Self::Context) -> Self::Result {
        println!("working on fib({})", msg.0);
    let mut sum=0;
    if msg.0 == 0 {
        Err(())
    } else if msg.0 == 1 {
        Ok(1)
    } else {

        for j in 1..1000000 {
            let mut i = 0;
            sum = 0;
            let mut last = 0;
            let mut curr = 1;
            while i < msg.0 - 1 {
                sum = last + curr;
                last = curr;
                curr = sum;
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        Ok(sum)
    }
}
}

fn main() {
let sys = System::new();

let a1 = Arbiter::new();
let a2 = Arbiter::new();
let a3 = Arbiter::new();

let execution1 = async {
    println!("exec 1 created");
    let sa = SomeActor {}.start();
    for n in 2..80 {
        sa.do_send(Fibonacci(n));
    }
};

let execution2 = async {
    println!("exec 2 created");
    let sa = SomeActor {}.start();
    for n in 2..80 {
        sa.do_send(Fibonacci(n));
    }
};

let execution3 = async {
    println!("exec 3 created");
    let sa = SomeActor {}.start();
    for n in 2..80 {
        sa.do_send(Fibonacci(n));
    }
};


a1.spawn(execution1);
a2.spawn(execution2);
a3.spawn(execution3);

sys.run();
}
```